# Need additional access to interact with Cloud Firestore application data

Tags: r, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have created a test collection on firestore and trying to access the database via REST API. But I get error status 403 to my GET request. Here's my R code for signing in and sending the GET request:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
api_key <- "API-KEY"

# Sign in ---------------------
sign.in <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  r <- httr::POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=", api_key),
                  httr::add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
                  body = jsonlite::toJSON(list(email = email, 
                                               password = password, 
                                               returnSecureToken = TRUE), 
                                          auto_unbox = TRUE)
  )
  return(httr::content(r))
}

user <- sign.in("example@email.com", "PASS-WORD", api_key)
accessToken <- user$idToken
email <- user$email

# Try to read data-------------------------
read.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  r <- httr::GET(sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint),
                 httr::add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json",
                                   "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)))
  return(r)
}

read.db("projects/gdg-demo/databases/(default)/documents/test", 
        accessToken)
```

#### Error message

The message in the response says:

> Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project gdg-demo before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=gdg-demo then retry

When I visit the URL mentioned in the message, I see:

[image]

The `Prinicipal` is my email address. This is not a company database, I am the only user and creator. How do I enable my access to firestore?

Comment: Found the problem: I was using project name in the endpoint when I should be using project ID.